# C++ input data into a struct variables from data file

Tags: c++, arrays, file, struct, fstream

I have a text file containing names and numbers. The name or the string contains 15 chars and I need to put it to the string. I'm working with structures.

```
struct grybautojas{
    string vardas;
    int barav, raudon, lep, diena;
}gryb[100];
```

After that, there are simple calculations which is done right, the problem is, it only reads everything once. After taking a first "box" of information, it just stops. Everything else in the result file is either blank as a string or 0 as an integer.

Here's my input function:

```
void ivedimas(){
    char eil[16];
    int b,r,l;

    inFile >> n;
    inFile.ignore();

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        inFile.get(eil,15);
        gryb[i].vardas=eil;
        inFile >> gryb[i].diena;

        gryb[i].barav=0, gryb[i].raudon=0, gryb[i].lep=0;

        for(int m=0;m<gryb[i].diena;m++){
            inFile >> b >> r >> l;
            gryb[i].barav+=b, gryb[i].raudon+=r, gryb[i].lep+=l;
        }

        inFile.ignore();
    }

    inFile.close();
}
```

And here's the file containing data:

```
4
Petras        3
5 13 8
4 0  5 
16 1 0 
Algis         1 
9 6 13 
Jurgis        4 
4 14 2 
4 4  15 
16 15 251 
1  2  3 
Rita          2 
6 65 4 
4 4  13
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    inFile.get(eil,15);

    Rita          2 
    Petras        3
    00000000011111
    12345678901234
```

I don't count 15, I count 14. Also, some of your lines seem to have a space at the end. You should rewrite your input logic to be *much* more robust. Read *lines* and parse them.

Comment: Yea, should have calculated the spaces, just copied and pasted data information without a clear look before.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
inFile.get(eil,15);
```

is reading the number that follows the name.

When you try to read the number (3 in your example), you get the next one (5) instead.